# Eclipse interface link to open related files

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, plugins, ide

This is not a code-related, but a pure IDE work efficiency question.

Is there any Eclipse plugin or built-in feature to provide "links" (shortcuts) to open other relevant .java files in the current project (or any files for that matter) from within a file.

To be more specific, here is an example of what I want to do:

- I added new functionality to a class called MyClass in my project.
- I also have a unit test file for that class called MyClassTest within another "test" project under a parent project.
- Now I want to jump to MyClassTest.java and add new unit tests.
- I'm lazy so I don't want to browse with the mouse in the Project Explorer (too many packages) and don't want to press Ctrl+Shift+T and type the class name.

I want some sort of shortcut planted in MyClass.java (or even a side panel window) which when clicked, opens MyClassTest.java for me.

This can be useful for the programmer to "link" related files (.xml, .java, .jsp) so he/she can open them quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) plugin solves exactly this problem for unit tests. You press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> while in a class to jump to its test class (and vice versa).

It even simplifies the process of creating the test class in the first place, with naming conventions and method stubs.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! This is exactly what I was looking for. For the time being, it serves the purpose, but the plugin doesn't seem to allow "relating" multiple files, not just the test classes.

Comment: @Qululu You are correct - this plugin will only ever help you with test classes.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in your described scenario I will right click on the "MyClass" (the text name in source) and go "References -> Workspace".  This will show me all other "related" classes referring to MyClass.  I can then double click on any of them to open which have appeared in the bottom search tab.

This also works great on methods to find out who is using the method in a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the "Open type" dialog work more easily in this case, if you have selected the name of the current class before opening the dialog. Your current class name is then already filled in.

Then hit <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Cursor right</kbd> in the open type dialog to remove the selection, type <kbd>T</kbd> (for Test) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the test class.

Comment: That being said, I highly recommend the MoreUnit alternative myself. :)